# How to pass variables from one action to the next one?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a form which collects a name, password and email_address which are all part of the User model. The same form also collects car_make which is part of the Car model. I know I can collect these as

```
$form->input("User.name"); or $form->input("Car.make");
```

and they are available in the action which the form submits to as

```
$this->data["User"] or $this->data["Car"]
```

But at this point I just want to save the User data and redirect to an action in the car controller which has the value they put in $form->input("Car.make"); available.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure you want to redirect to the cars controller? Or you just want to save that Car.make information?

If redirect, `$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'cars','action'=>'some_action','make'=>$this->data['Car']['make']));`

If save: loadModel('Car') if Car is not related to User in anyway. Then save the data using that Car model object. Just something like `$this->User->Car->save($this->data);`

Comment: I get it. As soon as I read your explanation I slapped my forehead. I knew you could pass parameters in a redirect (thats what I want) or a link like that but had forgotten. Gez... feel wick. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that information along with the redirect to your car controller. The best way to do this is either by adding parameters to the end of the url like adding `?car_make=MAKE`. Another option is to pass the make as a parameter of the method in the car controller, where the url would be `car/method/MAKE`.

Comment: hey there, thanks for the response. I knew it was a silly question ;)